# How to convert string to pkix.Name in Go?

Tags: go

Is there a function in Go standard library, any 3rd party library or other recommended approaches to convert string such as `CN=John Doe,OU=People,O=MyCompany` into [pkix.Name](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/pkix/#Name) or alternatively to [pkix.RDNSequence](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/pkix/#RDNSequence)?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/pkix/?

Comment: There I can find only function that returns pkix.Name as a string but my need is the other way around. I need to parse a string with distinguished name and convert that into pkix.Name.

Comment: Hi @bhargav-rao, I see you have deleted my answer here one month ago.  I submitted  answer which was a link to a library that does what I asked for: convert x500 distinguished name to pkix.Name.  I created the library myself since none existed to solve this problem and I thought I share it to others that might have the same problem as I did.  I'm curious to know why did it need to be deleted?